# How to prevent same site forgery?

Tags: javascript

I have a page which will fire an ajax request to the server to increment a value after user shared a post:

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'feed',
   name: 'Share',
   link: 'http://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}{% url "facebook_competition" %}',
   }, function(response){
      if (response && response.post_id) {
         $.post('http://mysite.net/shared/', {post_id:response.post_id});
      }
});
```

My site is protected by CSRF tokens, as below:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
        var csrftoken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        //var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
})
```

but how do I effectively prevent the user loading the page then firing ajax requests in console, such as:

```
for (var i=0; i<100; i++){
    $.post('http://mysite.net/shared/', {post_id:1234});
}
```

I have considered IP, frequency checking etc etc, but they are very ineffective.

Comment: For clarity: can you add how the etc. methods are "ineffective"? From personal experience I know there is not a lot you can do about someone stealing your data; if it's on the web and anyone can read it, they can steal it. (And "it's on the web so it must be free" is their usual defense...)

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a lot you can do to prevent it entirely, but you can combine the methods you've tried to make it more difficult. Ultimately you can consider generating some unique, one-time-use, token with each refresh that should be posted together with the post_id of the sharing action, so that your users would have to reload your page to update your counter a second time.

Also, (perhaps obviously) if your users are not anonymous, you can ignore their counter-increments of they have already caused one.